# Eclipse: How to highlight *.js.php files as JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, editor, syntax-highlighting

I've *.js.php-Files and would like to

1. highlight the syntax as JavaScript
2. supress warnings caused by lines like

   ```
   <?php if ($cond == true):?>alert("true!");<?php endif;?>
   ```

Does anybody know, how to tell Eclipse, it should handle *.js.php files not as *.php but as *.js?

Please don't talk about the pros and cons of mixing PHP and JS. It's just about the Eclipse issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just make it a .js and set in your .htaccess that it should be parsed as PHP?

Comment: @Johan Good advice but unfortunately not possible in this project. The files are already there and I'm the poor one who has to extend the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but this answer isn't a real answer:

You can add user defined file associations in

- Window->Preferences
- Options->Editors->File Associations

The problem is you can't add *.php and *.js.php there at the same time, because *.php includes *.js.php...

You can always add the JavaScript editor to the "*.php" to make it appear in the "Open With" menu, when you right click a file in the filelist.

For your second problem: I think the only way to fix this is by extends the JavaScript plugin. For example making  a comment. But that's a more complex topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I already know and tried the way you suggest. It doesn't work as I need.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem in a different IDE,

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>

$(document).ready(function(){ ... });

<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
```

Obviously, no IDE will correctly highlight that javascript since there is no indication it should be javascript... so I did:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
// <script>

$(document).ready(function(){ ... });

<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
```

This tells the IDE it's javascript, and while it's included in the actual source, it's commented so won't break anything

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the final solution but it highlights the code as JS - great idea, thanks a lot!